# At what stage of the selection process for a faculty position should I ask for references from colleagues?

Tags: etiquette, recommendation-letter

I'm second year faculty in my first position (practitioner/accounting). It is in a small business school. I am treated very well. However, a position has opened up at my alma mater. I am qualified, but I would consider myself a bit of a long shot. Not anywhere near 'impossible', but I certainly won't be the only qualified applicant.

With the 'long shot' part in mind, my question is about when should I ask colleagues/mentors to be included as a reference to take another position? That is, I know they will give me a reference. I also know they don't want me to leave and they had such high hopes that I would stay.

I want to do this the right way. But I don't want to secure references only to have them never hear from the university to which I'm applying.

My gut instinct is to ask them upfront, but I don't want them to worry over nothing (they had an unfortunate string of bad luck before me). The other choice is to wait until/if I'm contacted and actually getting the new position looks promising.

If this question is a duplicate, and you have a relevant link I would appreciate it.

Thank you so much!

Comment: It is hard to make any recommendation since personalities are involved. You lay out the dilemma quite well, but I think you need to be the one to resolve it. Good luck.